# Imperial to kg converter

Tags: java

An exercise on my problem worksheet asks us to write a method `public static double imperialToKg(double ton, double once, double drachm, double grain)` that converts masses given in the imperial system to kg.

We've been given a conversion table for this but what I don't understand, being completely new to java, is HOW can I get my method to differentiate between these input arguments?

For example if I want the method to return the kg value of 11 stone what's to stop it from returning the value of 11 tons (tons being the first argument)

```
public class W1_E2{
    public static double imperialToKg(double ton, double hundredweight, double quarter, double stone, double pound, double once, double drachm, double grain){
       ton = 1016.04691;
       hundredweight = 50.8023454;
       quarter = 12.7005864;
       stone = 6.35029318;
       ounce = 0.02834952;
       drachm = 0.00177185;
       grain = 0.0000648;

  }  
}
```

I've listed the conversions as variables but I don't know what to do with them...

Comment: Is that _really_ the method you should implement? One method with that many parameters, not many methods with one parameter each?

Comment: To be honest it seems a bit weird to me too but that is how it appears on the worksheet

Comment: And the parameters are immediately overwritten--I suspect there may have been a misunderstanding somewhere along the line. "What's to stop it" is your code. Without any details it's impossible to know what the actual goal is. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: If you're supposed to write exactly that method, then you need to use if/else statements: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Depending on the exact question wording, if/else might not be needed (if the sum of all parameters should be converted into kg). Then it's just multiplying all parameters with the factor and summing it up.

Comment: How would you go about this?

Comment: As i said, that depends what exactly the task is. Does it say, that it should return the sum of all given parameters converted?

Comment: Sorry, no it's infuriatingly vague for part a) it just needs to be able to convert imperial masses into kg, no details about outputs. The wording for part b) _"Write a main method and test your program by computing a person's weight in kg corresponding to 11 stones and 6 pounds"_. So I'm guessing it wants the method to have a return value

Answer (score 1):

For 11 stone, you would have to call that like:

```
returnedFoo = imperialToKg(0,0,0,11,0,0,0);
```

If you want to call it with a value of 11 tons,  you use:

```
returnedFoo = imperialToKg(11,0,0,0,0,0,0);
```

For our stone example, try:

On the implementation end, you would use something like:

```
public static double imperialToKg(double ton, double hundredweight, double quarter, double stone, double pound, double once, double drachm, double grain){
{
    double kg = (ton * 1016.04691) + (hundredweight * 50.8023454) + (quarter * 12.7005864) + (stone * 6.35029318) + (ounce * 0.02834952) + (drachm * 0.00177185) + (grain * 0.0000648);
    return kg;
}
```

This is quick and dirty; there is a multitude of better ways to do this, please confirm that the exercise is actually requesting we call the function like this.

Comment: This is what I thought, kinda seems a bit stupid to make us do it like this

Comment: yep that is how it is exactly how it is on the worksheet

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere does it state that you require one method to make all your conversions, but that you require a *main method* to test your code.

So, make an individual method for each type of conversion required, as an example:

```
public static double tonToKg(double val){
    return val * 1016.04691;
}
```

To test:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(tonToKg(11));
}
```